# Extracing specific parts of a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm reading a `byte[]` from memory and then converting that into a string. The start of the string would be something like this "NTDLL.RtlnitializeSListHead\0" where the rest of the string after the \0 would things I don't care about (there would also be more \0 characters in the string.)

I am trying to extract only "NTDLL.RtlnitializeSListHead" part of the string - This name will vary between usages so some sort of pattern would be needed.

What would be the best way to get this part of the string? I'm not going to lie my string manipulation skills are subpar to what they should be which is why I am having trouble with. I have thought about using regex but I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do this.

Comment: So, you just want the string up to the first `\0`? How are you converting it from a `byte[]`?

Comment: you can use `string.Split("\0").First()` if you can guarantee there's always `\0` in the string

Comment: Yea the string up to the first \0. I'm just using Encoding.UTF8.GetString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trim the end

```
var myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MyByteBuffer).TrimEnd((char)0);
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that on Windows "reading a byte[] from memory" will result in UTF8...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes this is little suspect

Comment: What should I be using instead of UTF8? I was originally using Default. Should I switch to Unicode?

Comment: @Akaion how are you getting these bytes

Comment: An RPM call to a remote process returning a byte[] as a buffer